# Update multiple rows based on multiple values

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, multiple-records

Lets say I have this:

```
Declare @passRefID as int
Declare @passTextA as varchar
Deckare @oassTextB as varchar
Declare @passPropertyA as int
Declare @passPropertyB as int


Set @oassTextA = 'Joe'
Set @passTextB = 'Smith'
Set @passPropertyA = 21
Set @passPropertyB = 23
```

**TSQL A:**

```
Set @passRefID = Select Ref_ID from TableA where ID = 10
```

The `Ref_ID` returns a value of 50

Now I want to use that value in another select statement which returns any amount of rows.
It looks like this

**TSQL B:**

```
Select UserID from TableB where FK_RefID = @passRefID
```

So lets say it returns:

```
UserID
34
56
87
```

Now I want to create an update for `TableC` based on the `UserID` that return previously.

My **TableC** layout of records look like this:

```
ID,   UserID, PropertyDefinitionID, PropertyValue
265,  34,     21,                    Bob
266,  34,     23,                    Barker
271,  34,     55,                    bb@abc.com
628,  56,     21,                    Jane
629,  56,     23,                    Adams
635,  56,     55,                    ja@abc.com
901,  83,     21,                    Tom
905,  83,     23,                    Thumb
910,  83,     55,                    tt@abc.com
```

I know I can use:

```
Update TableC Set PropertyValue = @oassTextA Where UserID = 34 and PropertyDefinitionID = @passPropertyA
Update TableC Set PropertyValue = @oassTextB Where UserID = 34 and PropertyDefinitionID = @passPropertyB
Update TableC Set PropertyValue = @oassTextA Where UserID = 56 and PropertyDefinitionID = @passPropertyA
Update TableC Set PropertyValue = @oassTextB Where UserID = 56 and PropertyDefinitionID = @passPropertyB
Update TableC Set PropertyValue = @oassTextA Where UserID = 83 and PropertyDefinitionID = @passPropertyA
Update TableC Set PropertyValue = @oassTextB Where UserID = 83 and PropertyDefinitionID = @passPropertyB
```

But my problem is that in **TSQL B**, those rows returned could differ. There could be 1 row or 100 rows returned and the **TableC** is constructed a bit different from the norm.

How can I create a dynamic `UPDATE` statement based on the amount of rows return using the unique USERIDs and the way the TableC uses the PropertyDefinitionID?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  TableC
SET     PropertyValue = CASE WHEN PropertyDefinitionID = @passPropertyA
                             THEN @oassTextA
                             ELSE @oassTextB
                        END
WHERE   PropertyDefinitionID IN ( @passPropertyA, @passPropertyB )
        AND UserID IN (
        SELECT  B.UserID
        FROM    TableB AS B
                INNER JOIN TableA AS A ON A.Ref_ID = B.FK_RefID
        WHERE   A.Id = 10 )
```

Comment: Okay...I just figured out this isnt going to work due to how my TableC is actually populated and created.  I will edit my initial post.  I appreciate your reply.  I can hope you can help out again or whoever can provide assistance.

Comment: That worked!  Brilliant!  I know need to tweak it a bit more to add more variables to it but hopefully I can figure it out.  Thank you again for helping me out.  This query is a different animal for me but I appreciate what you did.